# Динамическое добавление инпутов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеется модальное окно.
Логика работы, при нажатие на кнопку добовляется два инпута.
Делается через js?
Есть пример?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
 $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='first'>");
 $("div").append("<input type='text' placeholder='second'>");
})
```

```html
<div>
 <button>Click!!</button>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как задать id,как я узнаю какой будет, мне изьять данные нудно?

Comment: АйДи задается так id="id_name"

Answer (score 3):

```js
function addTwoInputs() {
  var inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.setAttribute("placeholder", "first");
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(inp);

  inp = document.createElement("input");
  inp.setAttribute("placeholder", "second");
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(inp);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addTwoInputs()">Click</button>
<div id="container"></div>
```